# Increase Session Timeout("InProc") of a user using API or service call

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session-cookies, session-state

On click on Button in our MVC Site We open another site in new Tab.
In that site user will be doing some operations with out touching anything in our site.
If our site is idle for 20 min session gets expired.
As User is working on another site after 20 min, user will be logged out of our site.

Other site is ok to call our any webservice or Api for every 5 min .
In our Api we need to write code to extend the session.

Session mamangemt we used is "InProc".

I couldnt understand how to reset or increase the timeout of Session.

Basically is there any way to increase particular user session("InProc") using Api's